# Shortest Floor Function

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to implement a floor function in as few bytes as possible.

A floor function is a function that takes a real number and returns the largest integer less than or equal to the input.

Your program should support both positive and negative inputs.  Since it is provably impossible to support all real numbers you need only support a reasonable subset of them.  This subset should include positive numbers, negative numbers and of course numbers that are not integers.  Such number systems include fixed-point numbers, floating point numbers and strings.

Your code may be a complete program or function.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with less bytes being a better score.

Comment: Any limits on the size of the numbers to be handled correctly? Need to treat negatives?

Comment: I ask about range because single precision IEEE 745 floating point runs up to 2^127, which is to say that 64 bit integers would not be sufficient.

Comment: @dmckee The problem definition states any real number, not just positive ones. As far as number size is concerned, let's assume that is not a concern (i.e., an answer that handles that case is not necessarily better than an answer that doesn't handle that case, unless of course it is of equal or lesser length).

Comment: In golfscript, this would be zero bytes since x is already an integer :)

Comment: Would `return (int)input;` (in Java, and possibly C, C++, and C# too) count as a "built-in rounding function"?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Type casting is fine, but this does not give the correct answer.

Comment: @DanielStandage Why not?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Try it on negative numbers and see what you get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### PARI/GP (10)

In gp (and some other languages) x%1 gives the decimal part of x:

```
f(x)=x-x%1
```

NOTE: For negative x, x%1 returns (1 - abs(decimal part of x)), so the above works both for positive and negative numbers.

Comment: @Joey: no it does not. Yields -4 for floor(-3.1234); -4 for floor(-4). What do *you* get?

Comment: x - x % 1 gives -3 for -3.1234, surely, when the expected answer is -4

Comment: @Nellius: **NO**, because -3.1234%1 = 0.8766.

Comment: Ok, I take that back, partially. Because the sign of the modulus result depends on the operand in some languages but not in others. For me, `-3.14 % 1` yields `-.14` (PowerShell). Now, if you'd be so kind to make a null edit so I can take the downvote back? :-)

Comment: @Joey: I had to clarify that anyway :)

Comment: @Eelvex Does PARI/GP have function syntax? If so, it would be fair to wrap your answer in a function as you have done with your other solutions.

Comment: @Daniel: you're right. Done.

Comment: You can shave off 2 characters with `x->x-x%1`. If not for the restriction you could use `x->x\1` which is another 2 characters shorter.

Answer (score 6):

### Javascript - 6 bytes

Usage of the arrow function declaration (as an anonymous function here) and a bitwise "AND" operator

```
x=>x&x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zbbC1q5CrYIrOT@vOD8nVS8nP10jwVTPVCEpNTk/N7VYQaU6TQPI16zVUdBFF9cFSyRo/v8PAA)

or alternatively using the bitwise "OR" operator:

```
x=>x|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zbbC1q6ixoArOT@vOD8nVS8nP10jwVTPVCEpNTk/N7VYQaU6TQPI16zVUdBFF9cFSyRo/v8PAA)

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can shave two bytes off, by removing the name of the function; as long as functions aren't recursive, [the name isn't necessary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9032/66833). Also, is it possible to provide a link to a site such as [TryItOnline](https://tio.run) where other users can verify your answer?

Comment: Surely. Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript, <s>50</s> <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 32 characters

```js
function f(n){return~~n-(~~n>n)}
```

Works the same way as the PHP one I submitted.

Comment: 32 chars if you drop the `;`

Comment: If you use ES6, it is 14 characters:`n=>~~n-(~~n>n)`

Comment: 8 bytes: `n=>n-n%1`

Answer (score 5):

## Python (20)

```
f=lambda x:int(x//1)
```

or, if the result doesn't need to be of type `int`, 15 characters:

```
f=lambda x:x//1
```

Comment: Two notes:
1. you can skip the `f=` part, as it is not recursive.
2. please state, that this is Python *3* code and not Python 2

Answer (score 4):

### DC (15 bytes)

Makes use of a nifty little trick that occurs during division in DC. Add a 'p' to then end to get output (it performs the floor correctly anyway), I assume that stuff is not already on the stack, and that input is in stdin.

```
[1-]sazk?z/d0>a
```

EG: `echo 0 2.6 - | dc -e '[1-]sazk?z/d0>ap'`

Answer (score 4):

## Python (81)

```
def f(x):return str(x - float("." + str(float(x)).split('.')[-1])).split('.')[0]
```

Comment: You can go down to 76 bytes by removing unnecessary spaces! `def f(x):return str(x-float("."+str(float(x)).split('.')[-1])).split('.')[0]`

Answer (score 3):

#### C (51)

```
int F(float x){int i=x-2;while(++i<=x-1);return i;}
```

Comment: Generally code gold answers are expected to be in the form of either a function or a complete program (here the OP has selected a function), so you need the `int f(float c){}` bit.

Comment: @dmckee: forgot that, sorry.

Comment: Why <=x-1? would <x not be exactly the same thing, but 3 characters shorter?

Comment: @Nellius: no, it's not the same (unfortunately).

Comment: @Nellius: only when x is an integer: compare "<=3.5-1" with "<3.5".

Answer (score 3):

#### LISP (26)

(Same trick as in PARI/GP answer)

```
(defun f(x)(- x(mod x 1)))
```

Comment: You can strip off the space before the `(mod`.

Comment: @Chris: :) Thx.

Answer (score 3):

### C 126 (including NL)

Doesn't use any built-in conversion such as `(int)x`.

```
r(float x) {
int
p=*(int*)&x,
f=p&8388607|1<<23,
e=((p>>23)&255)-150;
if(e>0)f*=1<<e;
if(e<0)f/=1<<-e;
return p>>31?-f-1:f;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### C (80)

Well it's not the shortest, but it's a great opportunity to show off my bit twiddling skills :D.

```c
main(){int I,X=0x7FFFFF;scanf("%f",&I);printf("%d",((I&X)|X+1)>>-(I>>23)+150);}
```

Answer (score 3):

### J  <sup>7 chars</sup>

```
f=:-1&|  NB. x - (x mod 1)
```

eg.

```
f 3.14
3
f _3.14
_4
```

Comment: Is there a good reason this isn't the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```c
int F(float x){int i=x;return i<=x?i:i-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z8zr0TBTSMtJz@xRKFCsxrEzbStsC5KLSktylPItLGtsM@0ytQ1tK4FK81NzMzT0FSo5uIsKALy0zSUVFNi8pR0gGaY6plqalojS4CFdaHitf8B)

```c
int F(float x){int i=x;return x>i?i:i-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z8zr0TBTSMtJz@xRKFCsxrEzbStsC5KLSktylPItLGtsM@0ytQ1tK4FK81NzMzT0FSo5uIsKALy0zSUVFNi8pR0gGaY6plqalojS4CFdaHitf8B)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, nice first answer!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to CGCC. If you haven't seen it yet, [tips for golfing in C](https://tinyurl.com/ycedgqn7) and [tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://tinyurl.com/y8kzo4vm) might be interesting to read through. :) Some golfs you could do to your current function: `<=` could be `>` (and the values swapped) for -1 byte; `return ` can be `x=` for -5 bytes; and you can remove the leading `int ` (it will give a warning, but we can ignore that) for -4 bytes. So in total: [`F(float x){int i=x;x=i>x?i-1:i;}` (**32 bytes**)](https://tinyurl.com/yyaxbmvp). Enjoy your stay! :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for the tips. I don't understand all your tips. It looks too nonstandard to me. So I only used your first tip.

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby 1.9 (12 <strike>14</strike>)**

```
 f=->x{x-x%1}
```

It's more a "for the record" type solution along the lines of the PARI/GP one.

```
>> f[3.4] #=> 3.0
>> f[-3.4] #=> -4.0
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around `x%1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL](https://aplwiki.com), 1 [byte](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

According to the updated rules, built-ins are allowed:

```
⌊
```

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Anonymous tacit prefix function abiding by the old prohibition on built-ins:

```apl
⊢-1|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfyf9qhtgsb/R12LdA1r/mv@T1Mw1jM04UpTMADiQ@tBnH/5BSWZ@XnF/3WLAQ)

`⊢` the argument

`-` minus

`1|` the division remainder when divided by 1

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 17 bytes

```
f(x)=x-x%1-(x<0)
```

port of the PARI/GP answer

```
f(-pi) = -4
f(pi) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 39 bytes

```
0 * * r 0
0 _ _ l 1
1 * _ l 1
1 . _ l 2
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?52b4094ddbcf7fe982b16d9a1de81ead)

Answer (score 1):

**C# (56 chars):**

My quick and naive answer earlier had a stupid logical flaw in it. Two approaches here, which I believe are both the same length. Double approach relies on the fact that casting to int removes the decimal part of a double.

```csharp
int F(double d){return(int)(d%1==0?d:(int)d-(d<0?1:0));}
```

Decimal approach relies on the fact that d%1 returns the decimal part of the number for decimal data type.

```csharp
int F(decimal d){return(int)(d%1==0?d:d-d%1-(d<0?1:0));}
```

Could save a few characters in both cases by returning their own type instead of int, but I feel a floor function should return an int.

Comment: You can use `float` instead and save a byte.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, <s>51</s> <s>45</s> <s>43</s> 37 characters

```php
function f($n){return~~$n-(~~$n>$n);}
```

This should be able to be applied to most languages that do not support the `n%1` trick.

Comment: Since this does not need to be an independently working program, I think you can safely trim the first 3 characters (i.e. the `<? `) off your solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl (23)

```perl
$_=int($_)-(int($_)>$_)
```

**Example:**

```
perl -ple '$_=int($_)-(int($_)>$_)'
```

Every value entered on input will now be printed "floored".

Its bass5098's technique, but smaller =).

#### As a function(36):

```perl
sub f{int($_[0])-(int($_[0])>$_[0])}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for shying away from regex?

Comment: This can be shortened by getting rid of the default variable: `$_=(int)-($_<int)`

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 19 bytes

Lambda from `double` to `int`. There are plenty of choices for types to assign to: `Function<Double, Integer>`, `DoubleFunction<Integer>`, or `DoubleToIntFunction`.

```java
n->(int)(n<0?n-1:n)
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##NY9NS8NAEIbPya8YCoVdSIZW/IC2KoIIHjzVm3hYs0nZdDMbspNIKfntcTQV5jIf7/O@U5vB5KEtqbbHqe2/vCug8CZGeDOO4JwmbecGwyVENizLypHxUIsMe3Yeq54KdoHwOYi6fA@vxC@XGVQ@hA7uJ8oflCPWinarR8rXG9JTsk0FPjte2ENwFhrxVXvuHB0@PsF0h6h/YySVkJT9MwELG6DyG@ZWzs63eJdBfo1XGdzgapwlyf4UuWww9IzyBrH/J6PQGsNqscR1JbClXWRgszkwmrb1p6conyirtd4KakylxukH)

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 4 bytes

```
]1%-
```

### Explained

```
]1%-
]   # Duplicate the implicit input
 1% # Modulo 1
   -# Subtract Modulo 1 of the input from the input, inplicitly outputting the floor'd result.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/z/WUFX3////xnqGRqYA)

Answer (score 1):

## x86_64 machine language (Linux), 11 bytes

```
0:       c4 e3 79 0b c0 01       vroundsd $0x1,%xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
6:       f2 0f 2c c0             cvttsd2si %xmm0,%eax
a:       c3                      retq
```

This requires a processor with AVX instructions.

To [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7RasMwDHz3V4iMgr0moU07ykizH5n3kMpxEnDs4ThgKPn1ecpaBgKdTjrdYdEjpvQyWjSL6q5zUKMrhw/2z0xtGDZitAE0V265mQ6iuPsuLN6CNs55HkW9MnR2DoBD66H//GoyGfEsY3eS8fIu4@FG84H6UUZdUdcyVvjg8JTV7M9hakfLxZ0BaHoLTzsFDRTH8q0mdIUH2DdlBQK2U4BvT2LNIdtp2CkqabMcVL4lFjlwTmv@Kp7xhegJChA1iVe2spR@UJu2n1Nhpl8), compile and run the following C program.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int f(double x){return floor(x);}
const char g[]="\xc4\xe3\x79\x0b\xc0\x01\xf2\x0f\x2c\xc0\xc3";

int main(){
  for( double d = -1.5; d < 1.5; d+=.2 ) {
    printf( "%f %d %d\n", d, f(d), ((int(*)(double))g)(d) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Oï
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f//D6//91TfSMAA) or [verify all values in the range \$[5,-5]\$ in \$0.1\$ increments](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9q4KJxdEeIflmlvZLCo7ZJCkr2lYeW//c/vP6/zn8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
O   # Sum the stack, which will use the (implicit) input-string if the stack is empty
    # (the input is read as string by default, so this `O` basically casts it to a float)
 ï  # Floor this input-float
    # (and output the resulting integer implicitly)
```

Although it may look pretty straight-forward, there are actually some things to note:

In the legacy version of 05AB1E, which was built in Python. The `ï` builtin would translate to the following code snippets:

```python
# Pop number
a = str(number)         # Cast number to a string
a = ast.literal_eval(a) # Evaluate this string as Python structure (so it goes back to a float)
a = int(a)              # Cast this float to an integer (which will truncate)
```

So whether you had string input or decimal input, it would cast it to a string during the code execution anyway, before casting it to an integer to truncate all decimal values.

[Try it online with `-0.5` as decimal argument.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9orfH/8Pr//wE)
[Try it online with `"-0.5"` as string argument.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/a@ka6BnqvT/8Pr//wE)

The new version of 05AB1E is built in Elixir however. Now, the `ï` builtin translates to the following code snippets (huge parts removed to only keep the relevant stuff):

```python
call_unary(fn x -> to_integer(x) end, a)      # Call the function `to_integer`, which will:
                                              # (I've only kept relevant parts of this function)
 is_float(value) -> round(Float.floor(value)) #  If it's a float: floor it down
 true ->                                      #  Else (it's a string):
     case Integer.parse(to_string(value)) do  #   Parse it from string to integer
        :error -> value                       #   If this resulted in an error: return as is
        {int, string} ->
            cond do                           #   Else it was parsed without errors:
                Regex.match?(~r/^\.\d+$/, string) -> int
                                              #    If it contains no decimal values:
                                              #      Return parsed int
                true -> value                 #    Else: return as is
```

Or as a TL;DR: float inputs are floored; string inputs are truncated.

[Try it online with `-0.5` as decimal argument.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9orfH/8Pr//wE)
[Try it online with `"-0.5"` as string argument.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a@ka6BnqvT/8Pr//wE)

As you can see, a string input gives the incorrect floored result for negative decimals. Unfortunately, the default (implicit) input from STDIN is always a string, so we'll have to convert it to a float first (for which I've used `O` - which only works on an empty stack in the new 05AB1E version built in Elixir; for the legacy 05AB1E version built in Python, the sum would result in `0` for an empty stack).

Comment: In your TIO the floor of (for example) -4.7 is -4, but it [actually is -5](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dhx4UQyk0syQCK/P@fmVeikJuYmaehqVDNxaUABAVFQLE0DSXVnLSYPCUdhbSc/PwiDV0TPXNNTWuIkqLUktKiPAUDa67a/wA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Davide Ah, I apparently had the output of negative values reversed. I thought the string input gave the correct results, but instead the float inputs give the correct results. Should be fixed now (at the cost of a byte).

Comment: Yeah it works now, I am sorry for the 100% increase in the number of bytes

Comment: @Davide haha, np. Due to lack of test cases, I simply reversed the intended outputs for negative inputs. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 7

Tested in Excel Online. Closing parens not counted toward score.

The only reason I posted this is because, oddly enough, it seems to work the exact same as `FLOOR.MATH()` with 1 argument.

```
=INT(A1)
```

Semantically, at least to me, it would make sense if this didn't work for negative numbers. However, `INT(-.5)` is `-1` for some reason. `TRUNC()` does what I think `INT()` should do.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```c
g;f(d){g=d>>9;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LbsIwELz7K1ZUkdYVsWI4lChpjnxFL6lfWHLsKnEqJMSvYwwiLexpdnYeK0ojREqm0SjpyXzKrqubc3qzXrhZKminKG1gh478U0MfDzfG@ggx7O1RSZRh/nYKNCUnAnlGFefRA2YNRQ3v8FBQ5G1bU9qQMyG/wUqIaoqL3Sz2nzEbNa4KDYVZQyG//GoNGWkXwoiGZoRLt6GPvNtDQ289LjH3bM6qfP5byy3jm2eiZh8vd77ZbdnumXr1V6zi9750Edr1ZkqlG64)

> Such number systems include **fixed-point numbers**, floating point numbers and strings.

I don't know why people insist on using floats... Fixed point is much easier

Uses 32-bit fixed9 precision. Abuses arithmetic shift right. Return hack, not much else to say.

Comment: I think you can save 3 bytes by cutting off `g;` and doing `d>>=9;`

Comment: Nah, that doesn't work. Undefined behavior is weird.

Comment: Oh all right, it was worth trying

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, 7 bytes

Machine code:

```
00000000: 66 0f 3a 0b c0 01 c3                             f.:....
```

Assembly:

```cpp
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .globl floor_sse4
floor_sse4:
        roundsd xmm0, xmm0, 1
        ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZFda4MwFIbv8yuCo5CCBm3L1n3ejF0PuttBsCaxgXxIEotj7K/PRRurkyDJOW@e97xaNU1WV1V/I3QlW8rgk1BKaG@FxqcXAFjnmdUweU0gIarY7Cnk0hhLnGM7NJW69SMAhJROEYIOydv7BwIwPjjQmCTuS/uyg9o0lnHRze1amqNcQMG8fegnlTWtpi4YKZWn8V1cGZb5qxKX3k9m0Wod5kmGCeeQzlNhhoBzSZX@NEY@G0GhZ84jatqjZJCvwffodY0LnyFRijgWrCjigb1sW@Za6YNm8aW6qIlIepg0A6c6e0cJv92hy9WobcJP8BwlKw5XdVifOkkhTy/Y4JpOmKD/ASCIoSqFRtO4Y4YC5xE3HrMtLjbLwj2@@9cPCbZ4vyz9v5/jvBj9@t@Ky7J2fSZVn6khJS7@AA)

Accepts a `double` in an `xmm0`.

Returns the floored `double` in `xmm0`.

Outgolfs the previous answer without cheesing with fixed point.

- Nowhere did it say the return type had to be an `int`, just an *integer*. Therefore, I can just skip the conversion code, storing the integer as a `double`. JavaScript has been doing it for decades.
- This one only requires SSE4.1.

Yes, I know the SSE conversion functions are a little redundant in the test code.

## x86-64 machine code, fixed point joke, 1 byte

Machine code:

```
00000000: c3                                               .
```

Assembly:

```c
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .globl floor_fixed
floor_fixed:
        ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHLTsMwELz7K1ZBlRyUWm0Rr4K4ILgiwRUpcv1ILDl2ZLslCPHrBKdp2gDFl/XueGd2x6yupwVjrWiCcAaS@wS8KozgwErqQGprXS5VI3j@5mhdC4d9aV2AJr1BKM@pr/IcPycPTy8Ywe4QZYLQuX83gTZgbO1EpDjAhbYrPeZGo/uyHd45Edr/e4Z50JHacq/VsLLooqBNBoKrPcCo1l0cTzFgld34ZmiiJRoNdFiChjBsuNsvjSYknS0nyjC95gJufeDKkvJuVKpoKLsK6n0M9rHTxtyuV1qATNEH2mmt44f0bqdYwikszi9IpP9EaGMVhyB8@NNWu@i9xMlEwqSACX81SQYy69fEMs2OfukwhEzTXiCSQEWVwQPvVmxOZhHep9MzMl@MC9fk8hd@Nc5/Ns/IbL4Va7@Y1LTw7VRX3w)

This function takes a 16-bit fixed8 in `ax` and returns a signed 8-bit integer in `ah`. It is not sign extended.

Nobody gave any specifics about precision

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal, 3 bytes

```
1%-
```

Push input, modulo with 1 and negate!

[Try it!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=1%25-&inputs=100.435&header=&footer=)

## Vyxal, 1 byte

```
⌊
```

Though a builtin.....

[Try it!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%8C%8A&inputs=100.435&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 31 bytes

```
,{.4{?<.(@!?\"!3'-<_".$>@>?~..@
```

```
    , { . 4
   { ? < . (
  @ ! ? \ " !
 3 ' - < _ " .
  $ > @ > ? ~
   . . @ . .
    . . . .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/1@nWs@k2t5GT8NB0T5GSdFYXdcmXklPxc7Bzr5OT8/h/39tEz1zMyMA) or [Try it online differently!](https://hexagony.net/#lzN4Igxg9gJgpiBcIA0wB0AWYB+APKgFAAICEWAOhSMQMwDkAtDgPpkioAkAfIZ1gH6pUhZCACWAOwAOAVwAuCEPQAMqAIwiJM2QFlocRAEMATgHMQAXyA)

Takes input of the form `+/-a.b`, ex: `+4.5` or `-0.1` or `+3.` Since hexagony doesn't have built in decimal types, the input must contain a `+` if positive in order to not cut off the first digit of the number. This answer can definitely be improved, but its a start.

Answer (score 1):

## [floor](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Floor), 5 bytes

`floor`

The floor function is a (the only) built-in.

### Full program (17 bytes):

Floor only accepts integers as program Input, so the program uses two inputs to generate a rational number to be passed to the floor function

`f:x y->floor(x/y)`

[implementation](https://github.com/bsoelch/floorLang)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 13

If the OP wants all functions to be non-anonymous, add `f=` to the front of each for two additional characters.

```python
lambda x:x//1
```

Since `x%1` returns the amount following the decimal point, this is pretty short (14):

```python
lambda x:x-x%1
```

The shortest using string casting I could come up with (40):

```python
lambda x:int(`x`.split('.')[0])+cmp(x,0)
```

Comment: int(x) wouldn't work since python floor will round up negative numbers while floor will always go to the lower ones. For example. floor(-5.9) should be -6, but int(-5.9) will return -5. you can take a couple more bytes and add a -1 if the original number is smaller than 1.

Comment: @Dat I'll just remove it, because `int(x//1)` has already been done.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 5 bytes

*The programming language used in this answer was created after the challenge was posted.*

```
it1\-
```

#### Examples

```
>> matl it1\-
> 5.6
5

>> matl it1\-
> -5.2
-6
```

#### Explanation

Pretty straightforward. It uses a [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) with divisor `1`.

```
i      % input                                                              
t      % duplicate                                                          
1      % number literal                                                     
\      % modulus after division
-      % subtraction
```

Comment: You should note that this language was developed wayyyyyy after this challenge.

Comment: @cat Sorry, I hadn't noticed. Disclaimer added

Answer (score 0):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse15), 13 bytes

Second place, ahh! (And this is a full program, not a function definition)

```
?&DUP &FRAC -
```

Take the fractional bit of the input and subtract it from the input.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 22 bytes

```
s/\..+//&&$_<0?$_--:$_
```

This is larger than my first answer, which merely truncated the number - so, for negative numbers, it wasn't correct. This was due to a misunderstanding on my part of what a floor function does.

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 1 byte

```
_
```

A builtin, thanks to the new challenge spec.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P@/8//v///4bGekaGxgA)

Comment: same for K [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P95Qz8j4/38A "K (oK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## AArch64 machine language (Linux), 8 bytes

```
0: 1e700000 fcvtms w0, d0
4: d65f03c0 ret
```

To try it out, compile and run the following C program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int f(double x){return floor(x);}
const char g[]="\x00\x00\x70\x1e\xc0\x03\x5f\xd6";

int main(){
  for( double d = -1.5; d < 1.5; d+=.2 ) {
    printf( "%f %d %d\n", d, f(d), ((int(*)(double))g)(d) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 16 bytes

Exactly ported from the [PARI/GP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/292/85052).

```
Fn.new{|x|x-x%1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkJaTn1@kYKvw3y1PLy@1vLqmoqZCt0LVsPZ/cGVxSWquXnlRZkmqBliZXnJiTo6GrrGeiaYmF4o0SEwPrEbzPwA)

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 26 bytes

Ported from the [Keg answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195954/85052).

```
Fn.new{|x|x.split(".")[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkJaTn1@kYKvw3y1PLy@1vLqmoqZCr7ggJ7NEQ0lPSTPaILb2f3BlcUlqrl55UWZJqgZYg15yYk6OhpKusZ6JkqYmF4oCkKAeWJXmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
:1%-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fylBV9/9/Uz1zAA)

<sup>Look ma, no unicode!</sup>

A port of the RProgN2 answer

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
Ḟ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjnn/D7c/alpzdNLDnTP@/zfVM9FR0AWSAA)

or a non-builtin answer

```
%1_@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/VMN7h/@H2R01rjk56uHPG//@meiY6CrpAEgA)

### How the second one works

```
%1_@ - Main link. Takes n on the left
%1   - Fractional part of n
  _@ - n - frac(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 15 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n//1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qT1/f8H9BUWZeiUaahoGegYGBoaYmF0zAVM8UiWeMxNbFUKuLqlgXqPo/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <strike>27</strike> <strike>25</strike> <strike>18</strike> 15 bytes

```lua
print(...//1|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDT09PX9@wxkDz////usZ6hiaGppYA)

#### Explanation

`...` variable-argument operator, returns the remaining arguments passed to the current function (top-level code block with all the program arguments in this case).

`//1` floor divides by 1.

`|0` bitwise OR, we use this to convert to an int.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
/Q1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xz/Q8P9/XWM9UwA)

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 8 bytes (2 instrs)

```
05000300 F8010000
```

**Disassembly**

```
    FIX $0,ROUND_DOWN,$0
    POP 1,0
```

MMIX has a builtin instruction for this. You can specify the rounding mode if you like, but you can use the default. (Options are towards 0, towards \$-\infty\$, towards \$\infty\$, or to nearest half to even.)

Honestly, I'd advise using a `FIX` directly, as opposed to calling.

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 4 bytes

```lua
n//1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z9PX9/w////RnrmAA)

Outputs with a leading `.0`. If this is forbidden, then...

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 5 bytes

```lua
floor
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z8tJz@/6P///0Z65gA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
1÷
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTElQzMlQjcmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0tMS4yMyZmbGFncz0=)

Floor divide by one.

Funnily enough, Thunno 2 doesn't have a proper floor built-in. For positive numbers, you can use `N` (truncate), but that doesn't work for negative numbers.